# Why does myArray.length show up as 0 during debugging?

Tags: javascript, .net

I'm stepping through this VB.NET / ASP application when I noticed this curiosity in a Javascript function:

[image]

Mouse over the array and you can see there are 7 items in the collection. Mouse over the `length` property and it says 0. Why is that?

Comment: How are you populating `pVarArray`?

Comment: @thefourtheye `var pVarArray = document.getElementsByTagName("input");`

Answer (score 1):

Length() tends to refer to contiguous elements - a string has a length for example.

Count() tends to refer to the number of elements in a looser collection.

Comment: There is no `Count` in JS; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array